# Provider doesn't show new page Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have this function below linked to a button that at the end should return a form page or an home page but it does nothing.

This is the code :

```
Future<Widget> submit() async {
    try {
      if (_formType == EmailSignInFormType.signIn) {
        await widget.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(_email.text, _pass.text);
        return Provider<Database>(
          create: (_) => FirestoreDatabase(uid: widget.auth.currentUser.uid),
          child: Home_page(),
        );
      } else {
        widget.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(_email.text, _pass.text);
        return Provider<Database>(
          create: (_) => FirestoreDatabase(uid: widget.auth.currentUser.uid),
          child: Reg_Form(),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showErrDialog(context, e.code);
    }
  }
```

I'm using a `Provider<Database>` because I need to call Firebase functions for Firestore and Storage so I need of a database but I read on the internet that maybe I should set a `Consumer` ( I never did it).
I was used to use Firebase functions as :

```
...some code...
database = Provider.of<Database>(...)
widget.database.setDataSomewhere
```

I think my way to act is wrong, trying to solve it.

P.S. : Both `signIn` and `createUser` work!

Comment: Don't know much about Provider (much happier with RiverPod), but it's my understanding that if you don't add a Consumer, nothing will get rebuilt based on a value change.

Comment: Mh, so I just need to add a Consumer, and what it should consume?